# unable to find valid certification path to requested target in java while authenticating Multiple URLs

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to perform ssl certificate authentication for Multiple URLs in a java program, I have stored URLs in a arrayList and pass them as a parameter to the method which performs certificate authentication and provides the response from the server.

The above method is working fine for single URL in case of  both manual entry and through the variable. But By passing these URLs through an arrayList is getting success for the first iteration from the second URL till the nth URL I'm getting this error.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1964)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:328)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at com.redeem.GetREsponse.getResponse(GetREsponse.java:108)
    at com.redeem.Check1.main(Check1.java:20)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
    ... 21 more
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: **unable to find valid certification path to requested target**
```

How to resolve this issue?

Code snippet where I have followed different methods

```
public class Check1 {
static ArrayList<String> arrayList;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    arrayList = new ArrayList();
    //GetREsponse get = new GetREsponse();
    arrayList.add("URL1");
    arrayList.add("URL2");
    arrayList.add("URL3");


    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)
    {
        //GetREsponse get = new GetREsponse();
        GetREsponse.getResponse(arrayList.get(i));

    /*  Thread1 t = new Thread1(i);
        t.start(); // try to check the status by providing delay
        try {       
            t.sleep(10000); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //continue;
        */
    }   
}

/*public static class Thread1 extends Thread
{
    int i1;
    public Thread1(int i)
    {
        i1 = i;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        //GetREsponse get = new GetREsponse();
        //get.getResponse(arrayList.get(i1));
        GetREsponse.getResponse(arrayList.get(i1));
    }
}

}*/


public class GetREsponse {
    static SSLContext sslcontext;
    static String Result;
    static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    static void getResponse(String url)
    {
        System.out.println(url+"~swa");
        try {

            sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(new File("C:/ssl/1.jks"),
                            "secret".toCharArray())
                    .loadKeyMaterial(new File("C:/ssl/certificate.p12"),
                            "secret".toCharArray(),
                            "secret".toCharArray())
                    .build();

            System.out.println("success");
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Allow TLSv1 protocol only
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslcontext,
                new String[] { "TLSv1" },
                null,
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

        // Directly configure HTTP authentication
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/ssl/1.jks");
      System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
        String username = "Username";
        String password = "loginpassword";
        String authString = username + ":" + password;
        String authHeader= null;
        try {
            authHeader = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println("success");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)`enter code here`
                .build();
        System.out.println("success");


        try {

            URL url1 = new URL(url);

            HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
            urlConn.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());
            System.out.println("1");
            urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authHeader);
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            System.out.println("2");

           int response = urlConn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("3");

            System.out.println(response+"");

            InputStream inputStream = urlConn.getInputStream(); 
            InputStreamReader i_reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream); 
            BufferedReader b_reader = new BufferedReader(i_reader);
            String str = b_reader.readLine();
            while(str != null)
            {
                sb.append(str);
                str = b_reader.readLine();
            }
            Result = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(sb.toString());            
            } 
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            } finally {
            try {
                httpclient.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there - you'll need to provide the code you're using so people can take a look.  The information provided isn't enough to solve this one.   Best of luck!

Comment: @CapnSparrow, Thank you for Responding, I have attached the code